# Multiple dynamically created comboboxes not triggering event handlers C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, combobox, event-handling

The following code is for a desktop application, not a web app.  I have essentially created a  dynamic row of controls to collect phone information for a contact.  The user can push a button at the end of each row if they want to add an additional row for contact info.

Problem 1: Each row has two comboboxes (cmbo_PhoneType & cmbo_BestCalltime) with eventhandlers attached. The event handlers, cmbo_PhoneType.SelectedIndexChanged && cmbo_BestCallTime.SelectedIndexChanged are not firing for the individual comboBoxes, for each row the user creates.

Problem 2:  The selected list item visible to the user never changes.  For example they select "Home"...the combobox will find it and append, but once the user leaves the combobox the selection (for all comboboxes) are defaulting back to the first item in the list.

If this were a web app, I would think it would be related to postback and viewstate (which I have not yet created the view state, but will once I get past these issues), but since this is a desktop app, I'm not sure.  What have I missed?

```
    public partial class frmTestPhoneRows : Form
    {
        
        int leftControl = 1;
        int StartPos = 88;
       

        ComboBox cmbo_phoneType = new ComboBox();
        MaskedTextBox msk_phone = new MaskedTextBox();
        TextBox txt_ext = new TextBox();
        ComboBox cmbo_BestCallTime = new ComboBox();
        CheckBox isMobile = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox verified = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox SubscribeToTexts = new CheckBox();
        Button btn_addNew = new Button();


        public frmTestPhoneRows()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createNewRow();

        }

        private void frmTestPhoneRows_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           

        }

        void createNewRow()
        {
            //connection string redacted
            MySqlConnection reConn = new MySqlConnection(sConnection);
            reConn.Open();

            MySqlCommand phoneTypeCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from lutable_phonetype order by Type", reConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter phoneTypeAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable phoneTypeTable = new DataTable();
            phoneTypeAdapter.SelectCommand = phoneTypeCommand;
            phoneTypeAdapter.Fill(phoneTypeTable);

            MySqlCommand bestCallTimeCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from lutble_bestcalltime ORDER by CallTime", reConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter bestCallTimeAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable bestCallTimeTable = new DataTable();
            bestCallTimeAdapter.SelectCommand = bestCallTimeCommand;
            bestCallTimeAdapter.Fill(bestCallTimeTable);


            ComboBox cmbo_newPhoneType = new ComboBox();
            this.Controls.Add(cmbo_newPhoneType);
            cmbo_newPhoneType.Size = new Size(121, 20);
            cmbo_newPhoneType.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.Left = 18;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 9);
            cmbo_newPhoneType.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.DataSource = phoneTypeTable;
            cmbo_newPhoneType.DisplayMember = "Type";
            cmbo_newPhoneType.ValueMember = "TypeID";
            cmbo_newPhoneType.DataBindings.Add("Selectedvalue", phoneTypeTable, "TypeID");
            cmbo_newPhoneType.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(phoneType_SelectedIndexChanged);

            MaskedTextBox msk_NewPhone = new MaskedTextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(msk_NewPhone);
            msk_NewPhone.Size = new Size(100, 20);
            msk_NewPhone.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            msk_NewPhone.Left = 143;
            msk_NewPhone.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 9);
            msk_NewPhone.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            msk_NewPhone.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            msk_NewPhone.Mask = "(000) 000-0000";

            TextBox txt_newExt = new TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt_newExt);
            txt_newExt.Size = new Size(61, 20);
            txt_newExt.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            txt_newExt.Left = 247;
            txt_newExt.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 9);
            txt_newExt.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            txt_newExt.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;

            ComboBox cmbo_newBestCallTime = new ComboBox();
            this.Controls.Add(cmbo_newBestCallTime);
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.Size = new Size(231, 20);
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.Left = 312;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 9);
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.DataSource = bestCallTimeTable;
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.DisplayMember = "CallTime";
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.ValueMember = "CallTimeId";
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.DataBindings.Add("Selectedvalue", bestCallTimeTable, "CallTimeId");
            cmbo_newBestCallTime.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cmboBestCallTime_SelectedIndexChanged);

            CheckBox chkbx_newVerified = new CheckBox();
            this.Controls.Add(chkbx_newVerified);
            chkbx_newVerified.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chkbx_newVerified.Text = "Verified";
            chkbx_newVerified.Size = new Size(75, 20);
            chkbx_newVerified.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            chkbx_newVerified.Left = 547;
            chkbx_newVerified.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 9);
            chkbx_newVerified.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            chkbx_newVerified.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;

            CheckBox chkbx_newIsMobile = new CheckBox();
            this.Controls.Add(chkbx_newIsMobile);
            chkbx_newIsMobile.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chkbx_newIsMobile.Text = "Mobile";
            chkbx_newIsMobile.Size = new Size(70, 20);
            chkbx_newIsMobile.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            chkbx_newIsMobile.Left = 626;
            chkbx_newIsMobile.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 9);
            chkbx_newIsMobile.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            chkbx_newIsMobile.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;

            CheckBox chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts = new CheckBox();
            this.Controls.Add(chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts);
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.Text = "Subscribe To Texts";
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.Size = new Size(156, 20);
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.Left = 700;
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 9);
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            chkbx_newSubscribeToTexts.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;

            Button btn_newAddNew = new Button();
            this.Controls.Add(btn_newAddNew);
            btn_newAddNew.Size = new Size(75, 20);
            btn_newAddNew.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            btn_newAddNew.ForeColor = Color.LightBlue;
            btn_newAddNew.Text = "Add Another";
            btn_newAddNew.Top = leftControl * StartPos;
            btn_newAddNew.Left = 860;
            btn_newAddNew.Click += new System.EventHandler(btn_addNew_Click);



        }

        private void phoneType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbo_phoneType.DataBindings.Clear();
        }

        private void cmboBestCallTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbo_BestCallTime.DataBindings.Clear();
        }

        private void btn_addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartPos = StartPos + 28;
            createNewRow();

          

        }
```

Comment: How can you access your variable `cmbo_phoneType` in your event handlers without a compiler error? Do you maybe have two variables `cmbo_phoneType`?

Comment: No.  I only have cmbo_phoneType declared in this one method.  That said, I do call this method when the form is initialized and then again as needed when the button is clicked, which adds the row.  I'm not receiving any errors in my complier and the program runs fine.  The controls just aren't firing the event handlers for the comboboxes.  The eventhandler for the button fires just fine each time.

Comment: Well, either you get compile errors, or you have a second declaration next to your local one.

Comment: Something is fishy in your current posted code… in both `SelectedIndexChanged` events there is a line that looks something like… `cmbo_phoneType.DataBindings.Clear();` … and … `cmbo_BestCallTime.DataBindings.Clear();` … ? … this is odd an “should” raise a compile time error that it does not know what `cmbo_phoneType` and `cmbo_BestCallTime` are and will say they don’t exist.

Comment: Those variables are defined “inside" the `createNewRow` method. So… if you do NOT get this error… then there is ANOTHER “different” `cmbo_phoneType` variable defined somewhere else in your code that you are not showing and this would certainly explain why the event is not doing anything.

Comment: No...absolutely NO compile Errors or the code wouldn't run.  No other declarations.

Comment: Edited the post with all of my code.  Perhaps the initial declarations are causing this issue that you are talking about.  that said, I had to add them in otherwise I DO get a compiler error when I remove them because the event handlers don't recognize the controls I'm working with.  So how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Additional information...If leave the global declarations and ONLY add the controls to the method like this:  ``` this.Controls.Add(cmbo_newPhoneType);``` I get a compiler error telling me the variables do not exist in the current context.  BUT if I remove the global declarations and only declare the variables inside of the method, I get a compiler error that tells me the variables are not recognized inside of the eventhandlers.  Am I trying to do something impossible here?

Comment: I get what you are sayin and I Swear...What I have posted above is LITTERALLY the ONLY code I have written.  What you see is what I have, with the exception of the redacted connection string.  I have a degree in computer science and have been working in the field since 2004, which is why this is blowing my head up.  It doesn't make sense.  I have even scraped this project and started a new one...same results.  Starting to wonder if I don't have a bug in my IDE or if I need to stop coding in C# and go back to C++.

Comment: Well…. Since I assume you will be adding multiple rows. Is what you may consider is making a SINGLE custom `UserControl` with the controls laid out as you want. Then simply create a new `UserControl` instead of calling `createNewRow` each time.

Comment: The problem you currently have is that each time you create a new row, you need to “create” new controls, like the text boxes and combo boxes etc… and this can become a problem to manage since you will have multiple text boxes and combo boxes and different rows which you will have to be able to distinguish. Making a custom `UserControl` that represents a single row and possibly a list of those `UserControls` should make it easier to manage.

Comment: Also have you considered using a grid? Other than a `MaskedTextBox`, the `DataGridView` has built-in column types for combo boxes and check boxes. It will certainly make it easier to manage adding new rows.

Comment: Thanks, John!  I initially started with a grid, but I didn't like how it made the GUI look plus it didn't work with an organic conversation for lead generation.  It left my client driving the conversation based on the order of elements in the form instead of the user listening and entering the details as they arise in the conversation so they don't end up sounding like a creepy sales person. Will try the custom UserControl, which crossed my mind.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Postback and viewstate is a different world. You have to relearn when doing desktop apps. Btw, tag q with winforms. Also, I'd go for WPF instead, especially if you have web experience.

Comment: @user14296112 … I will agree with Idle_Mind’s answer and it works; and I hope I am not missing something obvious, however, with multiple rows, you are still going to have problems identifying “which” combo boxes binding was cleared. You are NOT going to know “which” combo box fired the event. The same would apply to the text boxes if you wired up their text changed event.

Comment: I am just saying that if you plan on reading back any of the control’s values i.e. … if the user makes changes to a text box, combo box etc.… you are going to have a difficult time figuring out “which” control was changed. Is the control on row 1? Row 2?... Throw in more rows, and this problem only grows. I am guessing I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: Great thoughts, John and you are correct I did have that issue but I was able to create a workaround using iterations and other creative methods to track and/or address those issues.  For the purposes of this form, it's only used for input into the DB, which the adapter handles without issue.  The readback will occur on a different "profile" page and pulls the input directly from the DB.  So as long as the data goes in, it comes out as expected. This project has turned out to be more complicated than expected, but that's the fun of coding!  Thanks, again for your helpful input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wire up the dynamic controls, the SOURCE of the event will be passed to the event handler via the SENDER parameter.

Cast "sender" to your appropriate control type and then act upon it:

```
private void phoneType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
    cb.DataBindings.Clear();
}

private void cmboBestCallTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
    cb.DataBindings.Clear();
}
```